# Have Win10 Explorer open when flash drive inserted

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive

I'd like Win10 Explorer to open when a USB flash drive is inserted. My PC has never done that, although I see other Win10 PCs will. I am using RS5-1809 Pro.

Comment: Really? Marked down for a simple question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this.

First go to Control Panel and to Auto Play.

Set the default for your USB card to open in Windows Explorer.

Close out, restart the computer and test to see if it works. I set Auto Play to prompt and it does that